# confused with awk and shell variables

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk, quoting

I am trying to run a script that uses awk. There is no error it seems, but it doesn't create the file that I want. This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Number of domain:"
read number
echo "Domain name:"
read domain
more "file.txt" | awk '$2=='$domain' {print $1, "1.0"} $2!='$domain' {print $1,"-1.0"}' >"$number_domain.txt"
echo "DONE"
```

Basically, I want to create a document leaving all $1 that are, and changing $2, if it is $domain, write 1.0, else -1.0.

I am confused about how you can write the text with " " or ' ' and the awk ' ' and " ".

Comment: Why do you `more "file.txt" | awk...` ? Also, on the right side of the page, under _Related_ there are several links about _"passing shell variables to awk"_

Comment: What exactly are you confused about " " and ' '? What output do you get and what is the expected output?

Comment: @don_crissti I'll be sure to remove those in the future - I appreciate you clearing the confusion for me.

Comment: actually I had no output. I don't know why

Comment: First: Change `more file.txt | awk` to `cat file.txt | awk` (or better yet, use redirection). Second: I think you need a ';' after that first '}' since those look like separate statements to me. Third, and most importantly, do what Thomas Dickey said.

Comment: (OK, never mind the ';')

Answer (score 4):

The last item on this line

```
more "file.txt" | awk '$2=='$domain' {print $1, "1.0"} $2!='$domain' {print $1,"-1.0"}' >"$number_domain.txt"
```

is probably intended to be

```
>"${number}_${domain}.txt"
```

corresponding to the two variables which your script reads.  It would be nice if your script also ensured that the variables are not empty strings.  If they *are* empty, then the awk script will misbehave.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

To use shell variables in `awk` give them to the `awk` script using `-v awkvariable="$shellvariable"` instead of trying to paste them into the script itself, i.e.

```
awk -v d="$domain" '$2 == d { print $1, "1.0" } $2 != d { print $1,"-1.0" }'
```

This would "import" the value `$domain` into the `awk` script as the value of the variable `d`.

If the script in doing the right thing or not, I don't know, but you might want to use `${number}` rather than `$number` in the redirection afterwards. There is no variable called `number_domain` in your script, i.e. `... >"${number}_$domain.txt"`.